# Any way to convert Matlab script file and function file to python GEKKO format?

Tags: python, matlab, gekko

I have a my problem simulated in Matlab environment with a script file and corresponding function file for the same. I need to use them in GEKKO python. Is there a way to export those matlab files directly to GEKKO environment?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to help with the conversion.

- Use a code translator such as [SMOP (Small Matlab and Octave to Python compiler)](https://github.com/victorlei/smop).
- [Call Python Gekko from MATLAB](https://apmonitor.com/che263/index.php/Main/MatlabCallsPython). Below is an example of how to call Python from MATLAB.

**Python**

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
# Initialize Model
m = GEKKO()
# Initialize Variables
x = m.Var()            # define new variable
y = m.Var()            # default=0
# Define Equations
m.Equation(3*x+2*y==1)
m.Equation(x+2*y==0)  
# Solve
m.solve()
# Print solution
print('x: ' + str(x.value[0]))
print('y: ' + str(y.value[0]))
```

**MATLAB**

```matlab
% start Matlab from Anaconda prompt
close all; clear;
% Solve linear equations
% Initialize Model
m = py.gekko.GEKKO();
% Initialize Variables
x = m.Var();            % define new variable
y = m.Var();            % default=0
% Define Equations
m.Equation(3*x+2*y==1);
m.Equation(x+2*y==0);  
% Solve
m.solve();
% Extract values from Python lists using curly brackets
disp(['x: ' num2str(x.VALUE{1})]);
disp(['y: ' num2str(y.VALUE{1})]);
```

Other than that, there are no automatic translation tools from MATLAB to Python Gekko. These optimization tutorials with the same problem in [MATLAB](https://apmonitor.com/che263/index.php/Main/MatlabOptimization) and [Python](https://apmonitor.com/che263/index.php/Main/PythonOptimization) may help.